# Column in rich textbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am making a microsoft word like application and I'm using C#.Net.

I have a one richTextBox control, what i want is i want to make 2 column in richtextbox, same as we format our page in 2 column.

I couldn't find any property or method to do this. Can i do this?

Comment: You will have to create your own method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two columns in Winforms RichTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804958/two-columns-in-winforms-richtextbox)

Comment: Take a look at this answer to a similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8805070/127602][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8805070/127602